# Neo4j Multiple server instances Error 401

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j,I just follow the [neo4j official  manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-installation.html#_multiple_server_instances_on_one_machine):
 install two instances on one machine ,my environment is ubuntu-11.10.I had success start up the neo4j service and entered the websites http://localhost:7474/webadmin/  .But when I tried to  run  the "DELETE /db/data/cleandb/secret-key' command in its http console  .It returned error 401. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of neo4j are you using?

You have to configure two different ports for the two servers. Think you did this.

The `clean-db`-addon doesn't come out of the box, you have to [download](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-clean-remote-db-addon/downloads) it and and copy it in the `plugins` directory and adjust the `neo4j-server.properties` config file.

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.server.extension.test.delete=/cleandb
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty.delete.key=<please change secret-key>
```

Then you can call it for each of your servers with:

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:<port>/cleandb/secret-key
```